# How can I use Select in a Declared variable within a TSQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, stored-procedures, insert

I've got this code in my TSQL Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[priceVarianceTest]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime 
AS 

DECLARE @Week1End datetime = DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate);
DECLARE @Week2Begin datetime = DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);
DECLARE @MemberNo VarChar(25) = SELECT MEMBERNO FROM INVOICEDETAIL WHERE UNIT = @Unit;
DECLARE @MemberItemCode VarChar(50) = SELECT ITEMCODE FROM INVOICEDETAIL WHERE UNIT = @Unit;
```

...but it won't execute, saying:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure priceVarianceTest, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure priceVarianceTest, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

I wanted to then insert these vals like so:

```
INSERT INTO #temp1 (Unit, MemberNo, MemberItemCode) VALUES (@Unit, MemberNo, MemberItemCode);
```

...so I also tried this:

```
INSERT INTO #temp1 (Unit, MemberNo, MemberItemCode) VALUES (@Unit, SELECT MEMBERNO FROM INVOICEDETAIL WHERE UNIT = @Unit, MemberItemCode);
```

...but this was no more welcome than my previous attempt.

How can I, then, get these values. Is something wrong with my syntax, or my approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SELECT @variable = column`:

```
DECLARE @MemberNo VarChar(25); 
SELECT @MemberNo = MEMBERNO FROM INVOICEDETAIL WHERE UNIT = @Unit;
DECLARE @MemberItemCode VarChar(50); 
SELECT @MemberItemCode = ITEMCODE FROM INVOICEDETAIL WHERE UNIT = @Unit;
```

Or more simply:

```
DECLARE @MemberNo VarChar(25); 
DECLARE @MemberItemCode VarChar(50); 
SELECT @MemberNo = MEMBERNO, 
       @MemberItemCode = ITEMCODE 
FROM INVOICEDETAIL WHERE UNIT = @Unit;
```